# Install Ubuntu with Android in Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: samsung, ubuntu-for-android

hi I am a user of Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 and I just have seen an app "Ubuntu for Android"
I have Android 4.1.2 in my Note. Please tell me if I am able to use both Ubuntu and android in the tablet(like a formatted desktop which can use various OS at a time) and if it is possible please try to tell me the process

Answer (score 1):

First of all,  **Ubuntu for Android** isn't a 'mobile version' of Ubuntu. ie, After installing 'Ubuntu for Android' you won't be able to use Ubuntu OS in your android tablet. What it does is on connecting your tablet with your PC using and HDMI cable you'll be able to use the desktop version of Ubuntu.ie Your still will be in Android. The image below clarifies this :[image]

[Ubuntu For Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android)

So I assume what you expect is the **[Ubuntu For Phones](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone)** :The Mobile OS of Ubuntu.

I don't think Galaxy Note is ready for dual boot.
If you want an Ubuntu only tab, read the following.
Developers are trying to make the Ubuntu Os for a variety of devices. Samsung Galaxy Note is still under testing. Following are the current status.

[image]

> What is working?

- Touch
- Wifi (atm broken?)
- both Cameras (atm broken)
- Sound
- GSM (only mobile network)

> What is not working?

- GSM (phone/sms)
- Video recording
- May be more

  > How to install
- Download the latest the build for [GT-N7000](http://roms.gerrett84.de/n7000/ubuntu/daily/)
- Download the latest [quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/)
- ( Afterflash isn't needed anymore with 03-08 build)
- Make a Nandroid Backup
- Make a Full wipe
- Flash the ubuntu_n7000_X-X.zip
- Flash the quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip
- reboot

PS: The Rom will now build daily. Be sure that you use the latest daily rom with latest ubuntu daily.